# Bias of Estimator with square root of a sum of squared random variables

Tags: statistics

Got a distribution of
$f_X(x;\theta) = (x/\theta^2) \exp(-x^2/2\theta^2)$ for $x \ge 0$

where the MLE is calculated as
$\theta_{MLE} = \sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i)/2n}$

So now need to find if it's unbiased by taking the expected value of the beast.
How would this be approached?

Comment: You should use different notations for the parameter $\theta$ on one hand and the MLE estimator on the other.

Comment: Also, $f_x$ is not a density in your question.

Comment: I'd write $f_X(x)$, being careful about which is capital $X$ (the random variable) and which is lower-case $x$ (the argument to the (alleged) density function).  That way it's possible to understand expressions like $f_X(3)$, or like $\Pr(X\le x)$, etc.

Comment: The whole point of the $\exp$ notation is to make it unnecessary to write some expressions as superscripts.  I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: New to the tex syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb E_\theta(X^2)=2\theta^2$, the random variable $\Theta_n=\sqrt{\frac1{2n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k^2}$ is such that $\mathbb E_\theta(\Theta_n^2)=\theta^2$. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields $\mathbb E_\theta(\Theta_n)\lt\sqrt{\mathbb E_\theta(\Theta_n^2)}$ hence $\mathbb E_\theta(\Theta_n)\lt\theta$. Thus, $\Theta_n$ is a biased estimator of $\theta$ for every $n\geqslant1$. For example $\mathbb E_\theta(\Theta_1)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\theta$, but $\mathbb E_\theta(\Theta_n)\to\theta$ when $n\to\infty$.